# How to test a local keystore?

Tags: storage, key

I'm trying to add a test case for my function which is extracting key from the local Keystore.

This is how I'm creating an instance of a local Keystore and setting a key inside it in my test environment:

```rust
let keystore = LocalKeystore::in_memory();
SyncCryptoStore::insert_unknown(&keystore, KeyTypeId::try_from("test").unwrap(), "test", public_key);
```

Here the problem I'm facing is, I'm unable to extract the stored key from the keystone.
This is how I'm extracting it:

```rust
SyncCryptoStore::sr25519_public_keys(&keystore, KeyTypeId::try_from("test").unwrap())
```

This function is returning an empty vector.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the key existance with [has_key](https://crates.parity.io/sp_keystore/trait.SyncCryptoStore.html#tymethod.has_keys) method and list all available keys with [keys](https://crates.parity.io/sp_keystore/trait.SyncCryptoStore.html#method.keys). the `sr25519_public_keys` method forces to retrieve just the `sr25519` ones.

Comment: I'm getting sr25519 in my list but still, this function is returning an empty vector. –

Comment: you have created `public_key` somewhere that maybe is not true `sr25519` please use [sr25519_generate_new](https://crates.parity.io/sp_keystore/trait.SyncCryptoStore.html#tymethod.sr25519_generate_new) instead and iterate over all sr25519 keys by [sr25519_public_keys](https://crates.parity.io/sp_keystore/trait.SyncCryptoStore.html#tymethod.sr25519_public_keys)

Comment: I was converting the public key into bytes using .as_bytes(), but after converting it using sp_core::sr25519::Public:: from_ss58check(), the problem got resolved.

Converting a string of public key into bytes using .as_bytes() is the wrong approach, in substrate we should convert the keys into bytes using the substrate's internal components only.

Thanks for your help.